# Unable to change culture of .aspx page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, resources, localization

I'm unable to change a culture of .aspx page.

When I specify the culture by using page directive at the top:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="VideoPlayerPrototype.Index" Culture="ur-PK" UICulture="ur-PK" %>
```

Everything works as expected.

What I'd like to do, is to be able to change localisation when user clicks on a link.

Link:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="lang_ur-PK" 
                            ImageUrl="~/content/image/flag-of-pakistan.png" 
                            runat="server" 
                            CssClass="language" 
                            Height="64px" 
                            Width="64px"
                            OnClick="setLanguage" />
```

setLanguage method:

```
        protected void setLanguage(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ur-PK");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ur-PK");
            Response.Redirect(Request.Path);
        }
```

Invoking this code just reloads the page and doesn't load the correct language.

I have .resx files stored in App_LocalResources and App_GlobalResources:

Index.aspx.resx, Index.aspx.en.resx, Index.aspx.ur-PK.resx, Index.aspx.ur.resx etc.

Here is an example of control that must be localised:

```
 <asp:Label id="lblInfoWelcomeMsg" runat="server" 
                            Text="<%$ Resources:LocalizedText, Summary_Info_WelcomeMsg %>"></asp:Label>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to add this method in your code behind:

```
protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ur-PK");
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ur-PK");
        base.InitializeCulture();
    }
```

It would be better if you can make `BasePage` a class and add it there and then `BasePage` can be inherited on each page.

Comment: Here is the [msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx) that shows how to do this and also explains the difficulties with using post data

Answer (score 1):

You have to do this in `Page_PreInit` because localization can be change only in that event.

Note that wherever else you change the locale, then page declarative will override it, but you can change itin `Page_PreInit`

Only set a flag in your imageButton_Click() and then in `Page_PreInit` change the locale based on the flag value.

Comment: This is wrong - the culture needs to be set early in the Page life cycle, and this is normally done in the InitializeCulture method.  PreRender occurs far too late in the page life cycle to be any use - I suspect you probably intended to say PreInit.

Comment: @Joe, I'm sorry, you are right I meant PreInit, thank you for your consideration. I have edited my main answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your Click handler simply changes the thread's culture for the current request - this has been long forgotten when the page refreshes following your Response.Redirect.

You need to persist the new culture somewhere, then read it and set the culture at the beginning of each subsequent request (e.g. in Page.InitializeCulture).  Common places to persist it include:

- A database on the server.
- A cookie sent to the client with the response.
- In the URL to which you redirect (e.g. in the Querystring - e.g. ?lang=ur-PK)
- Session (but it will be forgotten if the Session expires)

Comment: Makes perfect sense. As always there are multiple ways of doing nearly the same thing in .NET. I think that the session is the most suitable for my requirements. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

By doing a response redirect, you start a new thread. Take the culture you want, save it in the session and then on page load set the culture to the value in the session.

Comment: I've been reading articles onlie and in the book. They don't use response.redirect at all and their exampls work (that's if I can believe the book). Response.redirect is something that I have added wheN I have attempted to store selected culture in a profile object.