# Currency formatting different on different sites

Tags: asp.net, iis, globalization

I have a weird issue here, and I'm not sure if its ASP.NET versions, IIS, or me doing something stupid (experience tells me its probably item 3.)

I have 2 websites that worked fine on w2k3, 1 is ASP.NET 1.1, and the other 2.0, with the currency being displayed correctly on web pages.

Since migrating these to a w2k8 box and IIS 7 I have an odd issue where the 1.1 site is now displaying $ rather than the local currency that the user browses to. But the 2.0 site works fine.

Both have IIS set to the same globalisation. (No culture, Client is false, UI Culture is English (en)).

Both sites are hosted on the same server, the only differences I can see are that;
1 binds using `<Databinder.Eval(... Price, "{0:c}")>` and the other binds to a property that uses `String.Format("{0:c}");`

So being as the code has not changed I feel that it is an IIS issue. But as both sites have the same globalisation settings in IIS I don't see that it can be.

So, anyone know whats goign on and how to solve it?

Comment: Check out this other SO answer for a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5763347/139917

Comment: I'll look into that tomorrow, but as this is an old / clunky site that used to work Im trying to avoid interfering if possible :)
Thanks, I'll post back if I have to go down that route

Comment: Is it possible to add some debugging code to your app? For example in the global.asax where you output the current culture? Are you using the same browser for all sites?

Answer (score 2):

Running IIS 10 site that was developed on a UK machine server 2012 was moved to a GCP default build server 2016 which comes US "out of the box".

On the website $ signs appear where £ signs used to.

I changed everything I could in Settings > Region and Language.  UK language, keyboard, Update & Security, Drive on Left etc.  Absolutely nothing made any difference.

Finally found it in Control Panel > Region. After adding English UK as a display language (and gettting rid of US English)

[image: Region > Administrative > Welcome screen and new user accounts.]

I needed to go to Adminstrative Tab, Welcome Screen and new User Accounts.  Copy the settings.

Now the site is finally displaying correct currency symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Regional and Language options from control panel on the new server and make sure they match the like setting on the old box.

Comment: They do, but if they didn;t then I'd expect both sites to be workign in usd, not one in usd and one in gbp.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, at least `String.Format("{0:c}")` and probably `<Databinder.Eval(... Price, "{0:c}")>` as well will use whatever the value of property [System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is.

It does not matter whether or not you set it on the page, the value will be assigned to it anyway. And it is pretty reasonable to think, that these settings will come from server settings, which from your description seems to be en-US. Thus $ as currency sign... You might ask yourself why it was working before...
Well, are you sure that you have copied all the configuration files?
Another clue might be, that you have emulated version of .Net 1.1 rather than the real one on your new box. It might be not 100% compatible...

Comment: the server is set to UK culture and UK currency symbols etc.

I believe that you could be correct, and the issue is stemming from the fact that it is not genuine 1.1.

I'm going to have to implement the code fix to force each page to the correct culture to get round this. (Or use it as a reason to get the budget to upgrade the site.)